# Find last non-zero value in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I build a test-simulation in PHP which I have te rebuild due to speed issues. The test has to virtually run through a certain amount of days, hours and then items within that hour.

I created an array containing how many items each hour contains. So:

```
$arrItemsEachHour(
0=> 0
1=> 0
2=> 0
3=> 0
4=> 0
5=> 0
6=> 0
7=> 0
8=> 1
9=> 2
10=> 4
11=> 5
12=> 6
13=> 7
14=> 7
15=> 8
16=> 8
17=> 8
18=> 7
19=> 6
20=> 5
21=> 4
22=> 4
23=> 1
24=> 0
);
```

This is the same array for each day.

I need to update the database after the simulation ran. I use the mysql insert query as follows:

```
$strSql = 'insert into results (id, day, hour, item, won, lost) values (1,2,3,6,2,4),
(1,2,4,7,3,4), (),()......();';
```

I need to know where the simulation ends so I can end the mySql string. The $strSql is outside the for loops in which the values are created and saved in the way I presented above.

So I need to make an if statement which closes the mysql statement when the day is equal to the last day (this value I have at hand) and when the last non zero value is currently in the for loop.

This is what my for loop looks like:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $this->intNumberOfDays; $i ++) {


        for($n = 0; $n < 24; $n ++) {

            for($k = 0; $k <= $arrItemsEachHour [$n]; $k ++) {

                            }
                     }
 }
```

My question is:

How can I decide wether I have the last non zero value in an array?

Answer:

```
$length = count($arrItemsEachHour) -1;
for($k = $length; $k >= 0; $k --) 
{
    if($arrItemsEachHour[$k] != 0)
    {
       // From $arrItemsEachHour[$k + 1] to $arrItemsEachHour[23] there are 0
    }
}
```

If statement:

```
if ($i == $this->intNumberOfDays && $intLastHour == $n && $k == $arrItemsEachHour [$n])
{ 'values();'} else {'values(),';}
```

Comment: I'd look into using `filter()` and `end()`. Filter out all zero values, then go to the end of the array.

Comment: you need get last non zero element form $arrItemsEachHour array?

Answer (score 5):

Begin at the end of the array, and loop until you have a non-zero value. The first non-zero value is followed by 0 in your array.

```
$length = count($arrItemsEachHour) -1;
for($k = $length; $k >= 0; $k --) 
{
    if($arrItemsEachHour[$k] != 0)
    {
       // From $arrItemsEachHour[$k + 1] to $arrItemsEachHour[23] there are 0
    }
}
```

Post Edited to fit the idea of Jay Blanchard

Comment: Great idea! Will try this as soon as possible!

Comment: Shouldn't the first comparison be `$k = count($arrItemsEachHour)`? In case the array changes length at some point?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Will always be 23 (0-23). 24 hours each day.

Comment: If there is always hours, it is not necessary. If it has to change, it is better to initialize another variable with the length of the array before the loop, and compare two variables. It's a little better about performance.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi I'm just not a fan of magic numbers. Makes code less robust and not scalable. A function written based on the premise of finding the last non-zero value of an array could be used over and over and could have sent to it an array of any length.

Comment: $k has to be $length-1 else there are 25 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? Remove zero values, take last element and extract key.

```
$arr = array_filter($arrItemsEachHour);
end($arr);
$lastNonZeroKey = key($arr);
var_dump($arrItemsEachHour[$lastNonZeroKey], $lastNonZeroKey);
```

Comment: Array_filter by default removes false, 0 and "".

Answer (score 1):

I would simply loop over the array first to find the last non zero:

```
$lastKey = -1;
foreach($arrItemsEachHour as $key => $val){
    if(!empty($val)){
        $lastKey = $key;
    }
}
for($n = 0; $n < 24; $n ++) {
    for($k = 0; $k <= $arrItemsEachHour [$n]; $k ++) {
        if($n == $lastKey){
            //Last!
            //Do some stuff
            break;//Break out the loop
        }else{
            //Not last
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @Ballantine's code is way shorter and more efficient I think though.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi Definitely, I'd go with Ballantine's if I was the asker :)

Answer (score 0):

end(array_diff($arrItemsEachHour, array(0)));